# gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor CPU usage

Tags: gnome, gvfs

Hello :) In past versions of ubuntu, I would see nearly flatline cpu usage at idle with nothing running. In 19.04 I seem to have a new culprit occupying #1 spot almost all the time at idle:  "gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor"  I've read basically what its for, but I'm wondering if its normal to see it using a consistent average of 6% cpu in top, ahead of everything else.  I've got no connected networks or drives, everything is pretty vanilla.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any network mounts or processes that are scanning the disk?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs